# reduce execution time of code

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

the below macro is used to compare the employees project date with the days which are populated in a multiple columns and give a count of how many current assignments an employee is working on a particular day.

for eg:- if RAnge Q3:Au3 is filled with dates of october 2013,
like q3:1st oct,r3:2nd oct,s3:3rd oct and so on.
my code is comparing these individual dates with the employees start and end date from sheet temp calc and returns a count of the no of assignments the employee is working on by counting the employee id. the code works fine but it takes ages for execution(beacuse there are around 50 thousand employees)
ive then applied filters after i get the data into the sheet in the first place to delete redundant data such as withdrawn,inactive and other employees.also another filter to remove employees that do not fall in my compare range but the employees is still huge and excution time is also large. 
could someone explain how i can reduce the project execution time and any where i can clean up the code for faster execution because the data is only going to increase.

in case i could not provide enough details i've attached my file in the link below please have a look.

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2CrBtuXvhrJSkgwbFZEWHYycTg/edit?usp=sharing

```
Option Explicit
Sub Count()

' x= no of columns(dashboard calender)
' y= no of rows(dashboard emp id)
' z= no of rows(temp calc sheet emp id)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   'Clear calender data
    Range("Q4").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents




    Dim i, j, k, l, d, x, y, z, Empid As Long
    Dim currentdate, startdate, enddate As Date

    x = (Range("n2") - Range("n1")) + 1
    y = Application.WorksheetFunction.counta(Range("A:A")) - 1
    z = Application.WorksheetFunction.counta(Worksheets("Temp Calc").Range("A:A")) - 1


  For i = 1 To y Step 1  'To loop through the emp_id in dashboard.
    For j = 1 To x Step 1 'To loop through the calender in dashboard daywise.
      d = 0
       For k = 1 To z Step 1 'To loop through the emp_id i temp calc sheet.

        Empid = ActiveSheet.Cells(i + 3, 1).Value

        currentdate = Cells(3, 16 + j).Value

            startdate = Worksheets("Temp calc").Cells(k + 1, 3).Value
            enddate = Worksheets("Temp calc").Cells(k + 1, 4).Value
            If (Worksheets("Temp calc").Cells(k + 1, 1).Value) = Empid Then

                If (currentdate >= startdate) And (currentdate <= enddate) Then     'To check whether the first column date falls within the project start and end date
                    d = d + 1


                End If
            End If


          Next
                 Worksheets("Dashboard").Cells(i + 3, j + 16) = d
       Next
Next         
    Range("q4").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Probably would get the best performance payoff by pulling your worksheet data into an array (or several arrays), operate on the array data, then write the results back to the worksheet(s). (You could also turn autocalculate off, but that won't help much if you have few (or simple) calculations in the worksheet(s).

Comment: i don't think there are any calculations in the sheet except to find out the no of days in the date range which is achieved by a single minus function.
initially i was using the array to store different sheet data then paste them into my sheet but it did not fulfill my further needs.

Comment: Yeah, so the array route is the best bet. It look like you are already calculating the size of your data with variables y and z. If you have two data ranges, declare two variant arrays (Dim arr1() as Variant, for example) and then you can assign the sheet ranges directly to the arrays (arr1 = Range(...)).

Comment: but y and z are simple count functions does it really make a difference ? If yes could you please explain a little more

Comment: All I meant was that it looked like you were getting the number of rows in the two ranges (from whence it would be easy to get bounds on your data ranges). As to why, reading from and writing back to the worksheet is slow, and that much slower if you're doing it for  50,000 rows. With the data brought into an array all at once, all your calculations will be in RAM. Then at the end, you can do a single write to the worksheet for all your results (or at least a lot fewer writes). The speed up should be tremendous.

Comment: oh really well thats brilliant because speed is what i need.
and i am sorry i do not have much knowledge about the bound and data ranges you are talking about..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32713/discussion-between-mathew-and-chuff)

Comment: hello again chuff,
i am currently working on your suggestions to improve my code,meanwhile the above marco is the one taking ages to run and i want to reduce that time

Comment: @mathew The suggestions above are definitely the way to go. I am just curious: do you need to stick to `VBA`? A simple `COUNTIFS` could do the job for you easily..

Comment: hello loannis,
could you explain how i would use countif here

Comment: At your example spreadsheet, place this formula in cell `Q4`:
`=COUNTIFS('Temp Calc'!$A$2:$A$20,Dashboard!$A4,'Temp Calc'!$C$2:$C$20,"<=" & Dashboard!Q$3,'Temp Calc'!$D$2:$D$20,">=" & Dashboard!Q$3)`
and drag it down. It counts how many times it finds an Employee ID for which the date in October is between the start and finish date of each entry. It just looks at the first 20 cells, but it is easy to expand..

Comment: won the formulas be seen as well, i think thats why i avoided this

Comment: Oh I see. You could hide the formulas if you protect the sheet (right click on them Format cells->Protection->Locked & Hidden and protect the sheet), but you may not want to take that route..

Comment: yea i dont want to do that :). thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Just so you know, `Dim i, j, k, l, d, x, y, z, Empid As Long` only defines **Empid** as long - all the rest are defined as variants. To have them all as long, you would need a line like this: `Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long, d As Long, x As Long, y As Long, z As Long, Empid As Long`. useful to know, as you could currently assign "s" to `z` with no error message

Comment: what's wrong with formulas? Even if you have to rprotect the cells in order to hide them this kind of work is what Excel was built for. Failing that, you should go ther **array** route as *chuff* said

Comment: yes chuffs solution and a filter is currently the two viable options i have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works for me..... And it is blazingly fast....
i thank everyone for their help :)

```
Sub assginment_count()
    Dim a, i As Long, ii As Long, dic As Object, w, e, s
    Dim StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date
    Set dic = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
     ' use dic as a "mother dictionary" object to store unique "Employee" info.
    dic.CompareMode = 1
     ' set compare mode to case-insensitive.
    a = Sheets("temp calc").Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Value
     ' store whole data in "Temp Calc" to variable "a" to speed up the process.
    For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
         ' commence loop from row 2.
        If Not dic.exists(a(i, 1)) Then
            Set dic(a(i, 1)) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
             ' set child dictionary to each unique "Emp Id"
        End If
        If Not dic(a(i, 1)).exists(a(i, 3)) Then
            Set dic(a(i, 1))(a(i, 3)) = _
            CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
             ' set child child dictionary to each unique "Startdt" to unique "Emp Id"
        End If
        dic(a(i, 1))(a(i, 3))(a(i, 4)) = dic(a(i, 1))(a(i, 3))(a(i, 4)) + 1
         ' add 1(count) to a unique set of "Emp Id", "Startdt" and "Finishdt", so that it enables to count as
         ' different match even if multiple same unique set of "Emp Id", "Startdt" and "Finishdt" appears.
    Next
    With Sheets("dashboard")
        StartDate = .[N1].Value: EndDate = .[N2].Value
        With .Range("a3").CurrentRegion.Resize(, .Rows(3).Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Column)
             ' finding the data range, cos you have blank column within the data range.
            .Columns("q").Resize(.Rows.count - 3, .Columns.count - 16).Offset(3).Value = 0
             ' initialize the values in result range set to "0".
            a = .Value
             ' store whole data range to an array "a"
            For i = 4 To UBound(a, 1)
                 ' commence loop from row 4.
                If dic.exists(a(i, 1)) Then
                     ' when mother dictionary finds "Employee"
                    For Each e In dic(a(i, 1))
                         ' loop each "Startdt"
                        For Each s In dic(a(i, 1))(e)
                             ' loop corresponding "Finishdt"
                            If (e <= EndDate) * (s >= StartDate) Then
                                 ' when "Startdt" <= EndDate and "Finishdt" >= StartDate
                                For ii = 17 To UBound(a, 2)
                                     ' commence loop from col.Q
                                    If (a(3, ii) >= e) * (s >= a(3, ii)) Then
                                         ' when date in the list matches to date between "Startdt" and "Finishdt"
                                        a(i, ii) = a(i, ii) + dic(a(i, 1))(e)(s)
                                         ' add its count to corresponding place in array "a"
                                    End If
                                Next
                            End If
                        Next
                    Next
                End If
            Next
            .Value = a
             ' dump whole data to a range.
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```